# Two For loops to increment, compare and find shift cipher keys

Tags: java, for-loop

I would like to modify a shift cipher java program I have to input a cipher phrase and plaintext phrase of alphabet letters, increment through both phrases sequentially and subtract each ciphertext letter by it's corresponding plaintext letter (one time pad-cipher - plaintext phrases will be of same length).

I thought to use nested incremental For loops for both phrases, but the inner loop cycles through all character positions and compares each to the first outer loop character before the outer loop increments to it's second character, and so on.

I need each loop to increment one character position at a time, and compare the two characters of both phrases, then both move on to their second character in each phrase to compare, etc.  I'd appreciate guidance in using For loops or other logic approaches to accomplish this. Code seagment is posted.

```
public class Cipher
{
  public static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  public static String keyFind(String cipherText, String plainText)
 }
    String keyPhrase = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.length(); i++;
    {
        int charPositionC = ALPHABET.indexOf(cipherText.charAt(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < plainText.length(); j++)    
        {
        int charPositionP = ALPHABET.indexOf(plainText.charAt(j));
        int keyVal = (charPositionC - charPositionP) % 26;
             if (keyVal < 0)
            {
                keyVal = ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
            }
        char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
        keyPhrase += replaceVal;
    }
    return keyPhrase;
}
```

Comment: If the two are of same length then why do you need a nested loop at all? Just use one loop and compare the character at position i on both strings.

Comment: Um. That works perfectly.  I was not considering this at all.  Tnx!!

Comment: I have one more question.  I realize that I need to account for a space as a character in addition to the alphabet letters, mod 27, so 27 characters including the "space" character.  I had public static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";  How can I allow for a "space"?

Comment: Never mind.  I merely added a space before the last quote.